# Using Calabash iOS with an app that has been signed for Distribution, not for Development

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

Is this is possible? Xcode throws errors when attempting to use Calabash iOS with an app that has been signed for Distribution, which makes sense - I'm getting an error with calabash on start_test_server_in_background.  It complains that I must use a Developer profile.  This means all automated devices MUST be provisioned.  How is this addressed on projects with a much larger device matrix?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I answered this question somewhere else already...

No.  It is not possible.  UIAutomation is only allowed when the app is signed with a Developer cert/profile.

> How is this addressed on projects with a much larger device matrix?

I have about a dozen Apple devices and, yes, it is a pain but there is nothing to be done about it.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the question off the google group and re-posted here due to the new suggested support model.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks for doing that.  I thought I saw it there!